# Неправильный обработчик в Media запросах JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, media-queries

Создал скрипт, который работает при ширине экрана 820 пикселей.
Данный скрипт при клике переключает цвет второму блоку **Block_change**, затем когда экран **больше 820 пикселей**, то цвет блока **Block_change** возвращается к исходному цвету(оранжевый) и клик по блоку перестает работать.

**Суть проблемы: При изменении экрана в большую, затем в меньшую сторону(820px), клик по блоку работает через раз, а по задумке кликер должен работать нормально.**

Я знаю, что неправильно повесил кликер, но не понимаю, как это исправить.

***На этом сайте в редакторе не показывается суть проблемы, попробуйте у себя локально на компе.***

```js
let Block_click = document.querySelector(".Block_click");
let Block_change = document.querySelector(".Block_change");
const MediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 820px)');

function RemoveClass(e) {
  if (e.matches) {
    Block_click.addEventListener('click', function() { // Я неправильно повесил обработчик, как это исправить?
      Block_change.classList.toggle("change_color");
    })
  } else {
    Block_change.classList.remove("change_color");
  }
}

MediaQuery.addEventListener('change', RemoveClass);
RemoveClass(MediaQuery);
```

```css
.Block_click {
  user-select: none;
  width: 200px;
  background: gray;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.Block_change {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  background: orange;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.change_color {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='Block_click'>КЛИКЕР</div>
<div class='Block_change'>Смена цвета</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Работает как вам нужно.

```js
let Block_click = document.querySelector(".Block_click");
let Block_change = document.querySelector(".Block_change");
const MediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 820px)');
let hello = false;

MediaQuery.addEventListener('change', (ev) => {
  hello = ev.matches
  
  console.log(hello);
  
  if (!hello) {
    Block_change.classList.remove("change_color");
  }
});

Block_click.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (!MediaQuery.matches || !hello) return

  Block_change.classList.toggle("change_color");
});
```

```css
.Block_click {
  user-select: none;
  width: 200px;
  background: gray;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.Block_change {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  background: orange;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.change_color {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='Block_click'>КЛИКЕР</div>
<div class='Block_change'>Смена цвета</div>
```

Comment: Кликер не работает =(

Comment: @Домик Все работает, ширину экрана меняйте и смотрите консоль, я вам `console.log` прописал для наглядности

Comment: Ах точно, я же сам писал, что на этом сайте проблему не видно =)

Comment: @Домик Я в редакторе этого сайта код писал, проблему видно нормально. Консоль разработчика браузера выводите справа и двигаете туда-сюда, меняя ширину сайта, вот вам и имитация смены `MediaQuery`

Comment: Все работает, спасибо вам =)

Comment: @Домик Не за что. Обращайтесь.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в том, что вы в функции `RemoveClass` при каждом ей вызове навешиваете новый обработчик события. И в итоге их количество всё больше и больше и больше. Логично, что если навесить обработчик события два раза - он сработает два раза - добавит класс и удалит. При трёх - добавит, удалит, добавит. И т.д.

Варианты решения:

1. Не оч. в функции навешивать слушателя, потом при событии клика отвязывать слушателя
2. Сделать навешивание слушателя отдельно, вне функции. И уже внутри просто вызывать клик на кнопке программно (`element.click()`)
3. Похожий на второй: сделать функцию смены класса и вызывать данную функцию при клике на кнопку и в функции `RemoveClass`

Comment: Попробовал ваш второй метод, не получилось.  Создал отдельную функцию function clicked(){   
Men.classList.toggle("visible");}  затем вызвал ее в RemoveClass в if через Block_click.click(clicked); Не сработал кликер =(

Comment: @Домик а что значит вот эта конструкция `Block_click.click(clicked)` ?

Comment: element.click() ну вы же мне ее дали

Comment: элемент у меня Block_click затем идет ваш метод click  ну и в скобках как я понимаю должно быть имя вызываемой функции?

Comment: @Домик а теперь внимательно посмотрите чем они отличаются? это раз. а во-вторых то, что я написал во втором пункте явно отличается от вашего понимания

Comment: @Домик " в скобках как я понимаю должно быть имя вызываемой функции? " --- я вам писал такое? нет. зачем выдумывать что-то от себя?

Comment: Без примера мне тяжело понять, я лучше понимаю на практике =) Был бы пример вашего второго метода, я бы без лишних слов все бы понял =)

Comment: @Домик Нет, я специаьно так написал, чтобы у вас был шанс хорошо вчитаться и подумать. В ином случа мозг просто копипастит и не пытается разобраться как должно работать. Вначале это сложно. Но потом проще

Comment: Вы меня запутали, я вас не понимаю. Мне бы пример, а так это пустая трата вашего времени =(

Comment: Поставлю вам плюсик за потраченное время =)

Answer (score 1):

Я считаю что тут тоглить не уместно, потому что можно запустаться в классах, мне кажется лучше всего через условие проверять на наличие классов и да правило camelCase почитайте как правильно называть переменные, вот мое решение:

```js
let Block_click = document.querySelector(".Block_click");         
let Block_change = document.querySelector(".Block_change");
const MediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 820px)');
                                           
function RemoveClass(){                                       
  if (!Block_change.classList.contains('change_color')) {
    Block_change.classList.add('change_color');
    Block_change.classList.remove('Block_change');
  } else {
    Block_change.classList.remove('change_color');
    Block_change.classList.add('Block_change');
  }
}

Block_click.addEventListener('click', RemoveClass);
```

```css
 
 .Block_click{
  user-select: none;
  width: 200px;
  background: gray;
  font-size: 22px;
  }
  
  .Block_change{
  margin-top:20px;
  width: 200px;
  background: orange;
  font-size: 22px;
  }
  
  .change_color{
  background: red;
  margin-top:20px;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 22px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JS+React</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
  <div class = 'Block_click'>КЛИКЕР</div>
  <div class = 'Block_change'>Смена цвета</div>

  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: И вам поставлю плюсик за старание =)